# How do I make navigation bar button item show my custom image as is?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

How do I make navigation bar button item show my custom image as is? Using the code below my button shows up as a solid color.  The outline of the image shows up correctly.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on iOS7
try to change the UIImage's rendering mode

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImage *newImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

use newImage to init the bar button item